# How long does it take to publish in IEEE transaction

Tags: publications, ieee

I'm preparing a paper about *Web UI Automation Testing*, and would like to publish it in IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering.

In this journal description they said:

> The IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering (TSE) is an archival
>   journal published **bimonthly**. We are interested in well-defined
>   theoretical results and empirical studies that have potential impact
>   on the construction, analysis, or management of software.

I searched their website, but can't find a clear estimation, how long does it take to publish in it, but I have heard from one of my colleague, it may take about 9 months.

I need my paper to be published within 2 months, what should I do?

Comment: I don't think that this question should be downvoted, and so I upvoted it once. It's a question whose answers can definitely help out others.

Comment: I have a paper in an IEEE transactions journal under review right now. I first submitted it 20 months ago (no that isn't a typo). Took almost a year to get the first round of comments. A few months to make revisions, 3 months to get the next round of comments, and so on.

Comment: Simply look at past papers.  It says on the bottom left page a paper's  submission time to acceptance time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I need my paper to be published within 2 months, what should I do?

You cannot expect your paper to be published within 2 months in the IEEE transactions even in the luckiest case.

First, you have to submit the paper, and from your question it appears that you are still preparing it. Then, once submitted, your paper should undergo the peer-review process, and this can take anywhere from a couple of months to around one year, depending on the number of revisions, and it can even end up with rejection. Finally, when accepted, papers are not typically published in the next available issue (*), because its composition is decided well in advance, and so your paper will be published a few months later from acceptance.

(*) IEEE Transactions have an online early publication service which is disconnected from the journal periodicity, but even taking into account this, 2 months is too short a time.

A detailed description of the various stages of the publication process, with typical duration, can be found in the answer to [*What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/55666/20058).

Comment: OK, I can understand, can you please explain more about _issue_, and how could it affect the time of publishing ?

Comment: @IsmailAl-Jubbah Many journals still schedule their publications based on mailing chunks of paper to subscribers.  Such a bundle of paper is called an "issue."  Depending on the length of a journal's "queue" and the issue your paper goes into may be anywhere from a few weeks to more than a year from its acceptance date.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Massimo's excellent answer:

**How often a journal appears has *nothing* to do with how long the review process will take. Those are completely disconnected things.**

Generally speaking, TSE is an *excellent* journal. 9 months of review time is even on the low side. I think 1 to 2 years is more common. 2 months is completely out of the question. Furthermore, the fact that you assume it *could* be done in 2 months leads me to believe that your chances of getting accepted at TSE without a much more experienced co-author are very slim.

Comment: I got your point, maybe first I should try to publish in less impact factor journal.

Answer (score 6):

Simply look at existing papers, and on the footnote of the first page, you'll see the date in which a manuscript is received, revised (maybe a few times), and then the acceptance date.  After that, look for the month+year when it appears in print.  This should give you the lag time.

Comment: That really make seance, I have got about 40 papers from IEEE in my topic, non of them published in 2015, I was wondering why no body publish on this field any more, and you just answered.

Answer (score 5):

IEEE Access: submission to publishing time is 4-6 weeks.
 IEEE Transactions on Consumer Electronics: submission to publishing time is 2 months.

IEEE Sensor Journal: takes 1.5-3 months. 
you can try IEEE Access and I think IEEE Transactions on Consumer Electronics will also covers topic area if your work presented in the Consumer Electronics Context.

Answer (score 3):

Imho, publishing withing two months in ANY journal is impossible - IEEE or low impact factor journal.

In communications engineering, the fastest way to get a paper published is to submit it to a conference, and even those had submission deadlines typically 3-5 months prior to the actual conference. Submissions to IEEE Transactions on Information Theory usually took 2+ years (!) to be published, submissions to other journals (e.g. AMS Advances in Mathematics of Communications) sometimes were published within one year, but only if no major revisions were needed.

Comment: As a counterexample, there's IEEE Access, which [advertises 4-6 weeks](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/ieee_access_faqs.pdf) from submission to publication. So no, not impossible (if you are not picky about sending your paper to an open-access mega journal.)

Comment: 2 years is really a very long time, but it worth trying, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about that? IEEE journals usually take 3 months to review. But it is true that delay is inevitable, usually due to lack of qualified reviewers.